# Access custom UITableViewCell from random func in swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have a custom UITableViewCell, where i am trying to change the cell.indicatorLabel background color from a func, but i do not know how to access the cell from that func

```
class mainCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var barcodeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicatorLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and i have a func called

```
func scan() {}
```

my cellForRowAt looks like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? mainCell   
    cell?.barcodeLabel.text = barcodeArray[indexPath.row].Barcode
    cell?.indicatorLabel.text = barcodeArray[indexPath.row].Indicator
    return cell!
}
```

i like to change the background color of the label from my func, anyone who can help with this?

Comment: When does `scan` get called?  How do **you** know which cell it should access?

Comment: use the table view method `cellForRowAtIndex`, will return the cell that you want and can easily access the outlets of your cell

Comment: Scan gets called when I trigger a button, and I want to change the background of the indicator label when this is done, and I want to do it from my scan function.